# Trouble identifying unknown component

Tags: transistors, diodes, identification, components, zener

[image]

Please help me to identify the component marked "SPWP". Even Google search is not giving any results and manufacturer logo is also not in list.

Comment: It's a diode.  It's marked "D1".   Since all 3 pins are connected, likely there are 2 diodes in the package, with either their anodes or their cathodes connected.    Search out the datasheet for the IC they're feeding "IR21844S"... Might be a hint in there as to what the diode is for.

Comment: All ic's are marked as D following the number . As you can see the ic ir21844s is also marked as D9

Answer (score 5):

Could it be: [MAX809LTRG](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.net/datasheet-pdf/view-marking/1068542/ONSEMI/MAX809LTRG.html)?

[image]

[image]

I think the SPW (4.63V threshold) is the type code and the other P the date code. Also you see both P’s are not identical.

Comment: NB: take a multimeter and check the vcc/in/vss compared to the datasheet of the neighboring IC https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/82798/IRF/IR21844S.html

Comment: Ok I'll do that

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a dual Schottky diode. [This](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds30266.pdf) P/N SDMP0340LCT comes very close except it's not got a valid match for the month of the date code.

Maybe functionally a wired-or for shutdown.